# Sort values inside dictionary python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary as shown below:

d={10: [5,2,7], 30: [30000, 600]}

How can I sort values which are inside list like as shown below ?

d={10: [2,5,7], 30: [600,30000]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way:

```
for value in d.itervalues():
    value.sort()
```